# Sequences that can have only one part using regex

Tags: regex, ember.js

for my application in Ember, I need to parse a string from a form, this string must be a hex number, it can only have one bytes, that depend of an other part of my code, but I think that there is a regex for this. 
Here, you can see that my current regex:

```
/([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:)+[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]/
```

With this, this is some example,

```
00:11:22:4a -> match
00:a2 -> match (coded on 2 bytes)
00:a -> no match (missing a nibble)
00:00:00:1q -> no match (out of range(hex number))
00 -> no match (abnormal, its an hex number on one bytes)
```

So my question here (or my problem, take it as you want), is that I can't have only one part of my sequences.
 Can you please give me some tips, that would be really appreciated.
 I'm sure this is basic knowledge or something, but I couldn't find any information for my problem. (plus I'm not good with regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `+` (1 or more) quantifier with `*` (0 or more):

```
/([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:)*[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]/
#                  here __^
```

You may shortened to:

```
/[0-9A-F]{2}(?::[0-9A-F]{2})*/i
```

Where `(?::[0-9A-F]{2})` is a non capture group, more efficient than a capture group.

Comment: Or a shorter and quicker `/[0-9A-F]{2}(?::[0-9A-F]{2})*/i`.

Comment: Well, `/[0-9A-F]{2}(?::[0-9A-F]{2})*/i` is more efficient not because of a non-capturing group, but because backtracking is reduced as the quantified part appears at the end of the pattern (no other patterns to yield text to after it). However, that is just best practice, not a must here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should write a book on regexs :-)

Comment: @Gangnus No need, see [here](http://files.hii-tech.com/book/Oreilly.Mastering.Regular.Expressions.3rd.Edition.Aug.2006.pdf),

Comment: I have a question, why is there no need to write  `a-f`?

Comment: @maje If you use key /i, the pattern ignores low/uppercase difference.

Comment: @maje: Because of the `/i` flag : case insensitive